# Time out although I entered correct credentials

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

No email is being sent from the stated email.
I get this error from time to time in my logs:

`app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection to edi161.nazwa.pl:465 Timed Out []`

I have to mention that the credentials are correct. Also pasting my parameters and config

config:

```
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    port: '%mailer_port%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
    logging: true
   # delivery_addresses: ['']
```

parameters:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_port: 465 
    mailer_host: myhost
    mailer_user: myuser
    mailer_password: mypw
```

Guys I am stuck, please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the connection and/or host/port/username/password. Please check the credentials from your email provider and check if you can connect to the email server through some other programs like Outlook or another email client.

Another thing can be the connection properties and firewall you have on your computer and it may be blocking the connection to that host.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I have tested it with Outlook and it does work correctly. I was able to add the email account and send/receive an email.   Website is currently on the server so I am not testing it locally, but it does not work still. Is there any chance that my host provider may be blocking it? Or is this some kind of code issue (code formatting maybe)? Id like to remind that it has worked before, it stopped working when i changed from Dev to Prod

Comment: @newdevedo Can you try with another port. Most applications which work on SMTP are using 587 for port? Can you tell me who is your hosting provider so maybe I can check their documentation?